# Ender 3 v2 intermittent problem - clearly visible layers

Tags: print-quality

I bought an Ender 3 v2 in January 2021 for my second printer. I have had an Ender 3 for two years and love the quality it prints. This new printer has been plagued with issues since day one. Creality sent me a new mainboard and fan due to issues. Even since then my printer will still not print consistently. I checked all my belts and made sure the bed is leveled.

I print a test cube and it looks perfect. Then I will print a bigger longer print and sometimes it looks 100 % perfect with smooth layers and then I will print the exact same print from the same memory card and there will be ridges every couple of layers and the print turns out very rough.

What would make this happen? I could understand if it always printed like this, but it is *completely random*. This is all from the same filament spool and I only use Hatchbox. My Ender 3 hasn't had a single problem in the two years I have owned it besides changing out the Bowden tube twice.

I use Cura for slicing.

The following pictures are of the same print on the same printer using the same filament from the same file.

[image: Photo of print showing layers]

[image: Close up photo of print showing layers]

Answer (score 1):

First, check that your belts are tight, on the X-axis and the bed. If not, tighten them.

Second, grab the hot end and wiggle the gantry, and make sure it is not loose. If there is any play at all, tighten the eccentric nuts.

If this doesn't fix your problems, check out this playlist I put together for the Ender 3 V2, it should answer everything.

[Ultimate Guide to the Ender 3 V2](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLPb81Z-Cw4oheuYfZy9GHORyQOY0aDgod)

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you've solved this by now.  If not, I'd be looking at all your bolts.  Tighten every single one of them.  Make sure none of the pieces are able to rock or twist or warp or anything like that.  After that, recheck your belts.

Comment: Welcome to 3D Printing SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 4.2.2 board, it may be a stepper driver problem. If this is the case, the only solution is to replace the board.

Answer (score 0):

Had exact!y the same problem. Belts were slipping. X belt slips just a touch and the layers move left, then if it slips the other way, its back to normal

Comment: Welcome to 3D Printing SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer. How did you resolve the issue? Please [edit] and expand upon your answer and update it with the solution. Otherwise it may be converted to a comment under the question. Thanks.